# Смена картинок JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте. Недавно получил код, здесь на сайте он работает, но почему то когда ставлю на свой сайт он уже не работает. Посмотрите пожалуйста может что нибудь найдёте. я уже второй день голову ломаю.

код html:

```js
    var gallery = {
      cnt: 0,
      container: document.getElementById("container_image"),
      timer: null,
      rds: "btn1",
      pos: 0,
      top: 1,
      init: function(i) {
        this.cnt = i;
        this.container.style.width = i * 700 + "px";
        this.timer = setInterval(function() {
          gallery.start();
        }, 1500);
      },
      start: function() {
        if (this.top == 1) {
          this.pos = 0;
          this.top += 1;
          document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
          document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
          document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else if (this.top == 2) {
          this.pos -= 350 * 2;
          this.top += 1;
          document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
          document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
          document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else if (this.top == 3) {
          this.pos -= 350 * 2;
          this.top = 1;
          document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
          document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
          document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        this.container.style.left = this.pos + "px";
      },
      slide: function(event) {
        var e = event || window.event;
        var target = e.target;

        if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() != "span") return;

        var id_click = target.id;
        var pos = document.getElementById(id_click).offsetLeft;
        if (id_click == "btn1") pos = 0;
        else if (id_click == "btn2") pos -= 526 * 2;
        else if (id_click == "btn3") pos -= 593 * 3;
        else pos = 247;
        this.container.style.left = pos + "px";
      }
    }
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  padding-left: 160px;
}
.prev {
  float: left;
  width: 5%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.photo {
  float: left;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.next {
  float: left;
  width: 5%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background: green;
}
.container-photo {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
}
.image-block {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.rds {
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 150%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.rds-bl {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<head>
  <title>--------------------</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="container/swap.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="container/swap.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      gallery.init(3);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="photo">
      <div class="container-photo" id="container_image">
        <div class="image-block" id="image_block">
          <span>Здесь может быть image, ссылки и прочее #1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-block">
          <span>Здесь может быть image, ссылки и прочее #2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-block">
          <span>Здесь может быть image, ссылки и прочее #3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="rds" onclick="gallery.slide(event)">
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn1"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn2"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn3"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот скрин с сайта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на сайте ничего не крутится, ничего не происходит. Если расширить блок то получается что все блоки показа построены вертикально.

Comment: моя не панимат ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯

Comment: подключите script внизу страницы... он не успевает загрузиться...

Comment: @CostaRaf не совсем понял, где и как подключить script в каком блоке снизу

Comment: @CostaRaf, дело тут не в месте подключения скрипта, на нём событие onload, что говорит о том, что его можно хоть в самом начале подключить

Comment: @Doofy а вы не знаете почему на моём сайте не работает, а тут всё нормально работает?

Comment: @Sambl, скинь файлами как есть всё, что необходимо

Comment: @Doofy скрипт грузиться раньше чем стараница и пытается выполнить действия над элементами, которые  не существуют..!! посмотрите в консоле...

Comment: @CostaRaf, скрипт действительно грузится раньше странички, но срабатывает он по её загрузке

Comment: скрипт падает на загрузке и больше не срабатывает....

Comment: @CostaRaf, куда он падает?) Когда документ полностью загружается, тогда только скрипт начинает работать. Возможно причина в другом, например в событиях, прописанных в html

Comment: @Doofy  в пропасть консольных ошибок.)) Возможно API javascript. К тому ж здесь   `var gallery = {`  в скрипте задается при загрузке....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда подключаете `<script>`, то подключайте его снизу(после) `html` кода. как в примере бнизу:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<head>
  <title>--------------------</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="container/swap.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="container/swap.js"></script>

  
</head>

<body>
<style>
#container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  padding-left: 160px;
}
.prev {
  float: left;
  width: 5%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.photo {
  float: left;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.next {
  float: left;
  width: 5%;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background: green;
}
.container-photo {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
}
.image-block {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  z-index: 1;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.rds {
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 150%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.rds-bl {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

</style>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="photo">
      <div class="container-photo" id="container_image">
        <div class="image-block" id="image_block">
          <span>Здесь может быть image, ссылки и прочее #1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-block">
          <span>Здесь может быть image, ссылки и прочее #2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="image-block">
          <span>Здесь может быть image, ссылки и прочее #3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="rds" onclick="gallery.slide(event)">
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn1"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn2"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn3"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      gallery.init(3);
    }
 var gallery = {
      cnt: 0,
      container: document.getElementById("container_image"),
      timer: null,
      rds: "btn1",
      pos: 0,
      top: 1,
      init: function(i) {
        this.cnt = i;
        this.container.style.width = i * 700 + "px";
        this.timer = setInterval(function() {
          gallery.start();
        }, 1500);
      },
      start: function() {
        if (this.top == 1) {
          this.pos = 0;
          this.top += 1;
          document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
          document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
          document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else if (this.top == 2) {
          this.pos -= 350 * 2;
          this.top += 1;
          document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
          document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
          document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "green";
        } else if (this.top == 3) {
          this.pos -= 350 * 2;
          this.top = 1;
          document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
          document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "green";
          document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        this.container.style.left = this.pos + "px";
      },
      slide: function(event) {
        var e = event || window.event;
        var target = e.target;

        if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() != "span") return;

        var id_click = target.id;
        var pos = document.getElementById(id_click).offsetLeft;
        if (id_click == "btn1") pos = 0;
        else if (id_click == "btn2") pos -= 526 * 2;
        else if (id_click == "btn3") pos -= 593 * 3;
        else pos = 247;
        this.container.style.left = pos + "px";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Либо вынесети весь `js` в отдельный фаил и подключите его внезу так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли, я думал не имеет особого значения где подключить.